# Error command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, python-2.7, gcc

I installed Scrapy on windows 7 64bit. When I enter `scrapy startproject tutorial` in CMD, I get an error:

```
ImportError: No module named `cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding`
```

To solve this, I want to install pycrypto. When I run `pip install pycrypto`, the next error was: `_Unable to find`vcvarsall.bat`_`, because I have installed Visual Studio 2010, to solve this, I installed mingw32 and set environment variable and disabled my antivirus and removed `-mno-cygwin` from `cygwinccompiler.py`:

```
if self.gcc_version < '4' or is_cygwingcc():
    no_cygwin = ''
else:
    no_cygwin = ' -mno-cygwin'
```

Became:

```
if self.gcc_version < '4' or is_cygwingcc():
    no_cygwin = ''
else:
    no_cygwin = ''
```

And now I get the error:

```
error command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

(Installed python 2.7 64)

Please guide me.

Comment: There should be a long error message displayed before that line: please copy the last chunk of it, as somewhere in there contains your *actual* error (failed with exit status 1 is just a general message). The last 50 lines would probably do it.

Comment: Stupid question: do you have `gcc` on your system path?

Comment: build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\winrand.o:winrand.c:(.text+0x47d): undefine
d reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.


error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Answer (score 0):

The easy thing is just to install the binary builds from http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto

Then you can attempt building the PyCrypto C extensions again at leisure:

- Visual Studio ships with a CMD shortcut that `vcvarsall.bat`. Use that shortcut to start `cmd.exe` and run `pip install` from there.
- (alternatively) Install cygwin instead of mingw to avoid having to change PyCrypto's build scripts
- Pycrypto have dependencies on [either GMP or MPIR](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/master/configure.ac) for bignums. Cygwin ships precompiled binaries of those. I'm sure there are Mingw based projects that have GMP precompiled as well.
- You'd need to either get prebuild binaries and headers for Pycrypto's dependencies or build them manually yourself

Comment: I install PyCrypto 2.6 for Python 2.7 64bit, but When I enter scrapy startproject tutorial in CMD, I get an error:

ImportError: No module named `cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding`

Comment: You can either obtain / product Windows x64 builds of `GMP` libraries and headers then build Pycrypto or you can switch to using a 32 bit build of Python and use the voidspace prebuilt Pycrypto binaries.